# How to "slice" or get a certain value from a subscription in BLPAPI from Python?

Tags: python, subscription, blpapi

I started working on BLPAPI for Python from BBG. And I got it to work. Now I get market data outputs, but I don't know how to handle them properly (heck I don't even know what kind of data this is).
The code:

```
def main():
    options = parseCmdLine()

    # Fill SessionOptions
    sessionOptions = blpapi.SessionOptions()
    sessionOptions.setServerHost(options.host)
    sessionOptions.setServerPort(options.port)

    print("Connecting to %s:%d" % (options.host, options.port))

    # Create a Session
    session = blpapi.Session(sessionOptions)

    # Start a Session
    if not session.start():
        print("Failed to start session.")
        return

    if not session.openService("//blp/mktdata"):
        print("Failed to open //blp/mktdata")
        return

    security1 = "IBM US Equity"
    #security2 = "/cusip/912828GM6@BGN"

    subscriptions = blpapi.SubscriptionList()
    subscriptions.add(security1,
                      "LAST_PRICE,BID,ASK",
                      "",
                      blpapi.CorrelationId(security1))
    session.subscribe(subscriptions)

    try:
        # Process received events
        eventCount = 0
        while(True):
            # We provide timeout to give the chance to Ctrl+C handling:
            event = session.nextEvent(100)
            for msg in event:
                if event.eventType() == blpapi.Event.SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS or \
                        event.eventType() == blpapi.Event.SUBSCRIPTION_DATA:

                    print(msg)

            if event.eventType() == blpapi.Event.SUBSCRIPTION_DATA:
                eventCount += 1
                if eventCount >= options.maxEvents:
                    break
```

The output:

```
IBM US Equity 
02MAY2020_11:59:47.298 1424:22272 WARN blpapi_selfdescvalueelementimpl.cpp:846 SelfDescValueElementImpl Invalid dateortime wire value: 20121301 
MarketDataEvents = {
    MKTDATA_EVENT_TYPE = SUMMARY
    MKTDATA_EVENT_SUBTYPE = INITPAINT
    BID = 121.820000
    ASK = 121.830000
    BEST_BID = 121.820000
    BEST_ASK = 121.830000
    BID_ALL_SESSION = 121.750000
    ASK_ALL_SESSION = 121.960000
    BID_SIZE_ALL_SESSIONS_RT = 4
    ASK_SIZE_ALL_SESSIONS_RT =
```

So my question is how can I get for instance: BEST_BID on every event update, so I get a variable with 121.820000 as number.

Answer (score 2):

I found it. 
https://bloomberg.github.io/blpapi-docs/python/3.13/_autosummary/blpapi.Element.html#

print(msg.getElement("BEST_BID"))

And probably need to make a check if element is there using msg.hasElement().

Comment: Do you know how can I get the same with `eventHandler.processEvent` instead of `nextEvent`? I'm getting the same format of `MarkjetDataEvents` but it will throw `Attempt to access unavailable sub-element 'ASK'of element 'MarketDataEvents'` on  `print(msg.getElement["ASK"])`. I think my issue is that I need only `SUMMARY` event type but after that I'm getting also `QUOTE` and `TRADE` even types. Is there any way to subscribe only to that event?